# Sitecore Rocks, copy value from one field to another

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-rocks

I have the following Sitecore Rocks query.   I want to make the value of the *Background Static Image* field match the value of the *Background Image* field.

> update set @#Background Static Image# = @#Background Image# from
>   /sitecore/content/Sites/MySite/Assets/Global/#Hero
>   Items#//*[@@templatename = 'Hero'];

When I run the update it says (131 items affected.).   But, the *Background Static Image* field never gets updated.

This seems to be the correct syntax based on http://vsplugins.sitecore.net/Sitecore-Query-Update-Samples.ashx

Comment: Try clearing your Sitecore caches from `/sitecore/admin/cache.aspx` and checking the raw values again.

Comment: That was my immediate thought, but nope doesn't help.   If I go poke in the Versioned Fields table, I don't even see a row for the field in the database.

Comment: You'e right, this seems like a bug or something that is no longer supported. Suggest you use [Sitecore PowerShell Extensions](http://blog.najmanowicz.com/sitecore-powershell-console/) instead

Comment: @jammykam You are right, it appears to be a bug.   See the weird workaround in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out.   To get it to work, I had to prepend an empty string (two single quotes and a plus sign) to the value.

> update set @#Background Static Image# = '' + @#Background Image# from
>   /sitecore/content/Sites/MySite/Assets/Global/#Hero
>   Items#//*[@@templatename = 'Hero'];